# Xcode Button missing from element tree hierarchy

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode11, xcuitest

Using:
Xcode 11.3.1
Simulators 13.3

We have a table cell in our app that has 2 text fields and a button.  When we view the element hierarchy, the button does not appear.  Below is what it appears like in the app and the element hierarchy obtained by running `po XCUIApplication()`

[image]

[image]

However, if I remove both text elements and leave just the button, then it **does** appear in the hierarchy tree:

[image]

[image]

This is what the xib file looks like:

[image]

It is set to enabled for accessibility as well:

[image]

Has anyone ran into this issue before? If so, is there a workaround to get the button to appear in the tree hierarchy?

Note: It **does** appear in the tree hierarchy (even when text elements are present in the cell) for the XS Max and XR simulators, but does not appear on the the others.